# copy rows in the same table with all same values except 2

Tags: mysql

I've table `abc` in which I've 8 columns .

I want to copy and insert the rows in the same table with two column values separately defined.

I want to accomplish something like this.

```
INSERT INTO abc(*,column1,column2) SELECT *,'VAL1','VAL2' FROM abc
```

As you can see in the above query I am trying to copy all the columns except `column1` and `column2` in which I am inserting my own values. Is it possible or I've to write all the column names ?

**Note:**

Please make sure , I've to insert the primary key value by myself as per requirement of the application . So if I am directly going to copy the columns , it will give a primary key constraint error .

Comment: Why don't you update the 2 values in question instead of copy the table to itself? `UPDATE abc SET column1 = 'VAL1', column2 = 'VAL2'`

Comment: @Prix yes that's also in my mind , but I was just wondering if it was possible this way in order to complete the task in a single query.

Comment: The way you want it done is the same as using `UPDATE` it will have the same effect you have described.

Comment: but this will also create a `primary key constraint` error because I want to insert a separate primary key while inserting the rest of the columns as they are . Yes I am inserting primary keys manually , there is no auto_increment